# Convert a Date to a String in Sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Is there a way to convert a date to a string in Sqlite? For example I am trying to get the min date in Sqlite:

```
SELECT MIN(StartDate) AS MinDate FROM TableName
```

I know in SQL Server I would use the SQL below to accomplish what I am trying to do:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MIN(StartDate), 101) AS MinDate FROM TableName
```

Thanks!

Comment: How are you storing the dates in your table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT MIN(DATE('your-date-here')) as MinDate FROM TableName
```

And make sure your-date-here follows a well understood format by SQLite (See the [Time String](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). section in the documentation)

Comment: The result for this is NULL when I run it. Also, "your-date-here" is a DATETIME column from my table. I'm not sure if that makes a difference?

Comment: If it's returning NULL, it's because your argument isn't a valid date.  Presumably, you're dates as strings.  If so, make sure you use 'YYYY-MM-DD' format.

Comment: SQLite stores dates as strings...as Dan says, you're probably not using a rightly formatted date...

Comment: Here is an example of one of my dates from the database:
    "2010-06-15 09:50:00 -0400"

I'm guessing the "-0400" is what was causing the problem, I removed that and it now works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

SQLite doesn't have a date type.  What `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` actually returns is a string in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.  The [date/time formatting/calculation functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) accept strings in this format, or alternatively, numbers, which are interpreted as [Julian dates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) unless you use the ['unixepoch'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) modifier.

So, "converting a date to a string" depends on how you're storing your dates:

- If you're storing them as Julian dates, use `DATE(YourDateColumn)`.
- If you're storing them as Unix times, use `DATE(YourDateColumn, 'unixepoch')`.
- If you're storing them as ISO 8601 strings, then, well you don't have to do anything.  Unless you want a string in a different format, in which case you should use the `STRFTIME` function.
- If you're storing them as some other string format, you really should consider using one of the supported formats so you can use the date/time functions.

In all three date formats, chronological order is the same as lexicographical order, so the `MIN` function works as expected.

Comment: Can confirm that `DATE(ZYOUR_COLUMN_NAME, 'unixepoch')` works for `CoreData` generated SQLite files.

Answer (score 4):

try this!!

```
 SELECT * FROM Table WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d',CreatedAt) BETWEEN '2014-10-07' AND '2014-10-17'
```