# SQL composite key from datetime functions

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime, composite-key

I'm trying to make a composite key using some of SQLite's functions but the columns 'newdate' and 'newckey' and appearing blank when I run the query. Any advice?

```
SELECT *,
       (repeat||date) as 'ckey', 
       (repeat||newdate) as 'newckey' 
FROM (SELECT transactions.id,
             transactions.repeat,
             transactions.date, 
             datetime(transactions.date,'+'||repeattransactions.interval||' days') 
                   AS 'newdate' 
      FROM transactions, repeattransactions 
      WHERE transactions.repeat = repeattransactions.id
     )
```

Comment: Are date and newdate already string types?

Comment: No date is a sqlite DATE type

Comment: But I don't see how this would make a difference, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018018/convert-a-date-to-a-string-in-sqlite

Comment: WHOOPS! Just double checked the format of my dates and I had the extraneous timezone info too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the SQL itself, the dates were stored in the wrong format, including the local timezone info